# Read values of web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7, web-config

I want to read values of different sections of web.config files.

for e.g.

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="4.5" 
maxRequestLength="102400" />
<pages validateRequest="true"></pages>
</system.web>
```

In this system.web section I want to read httpRuntime requestValidationMode 
   value. In pages I want to read value for validateRequest.

Also, I want to read values of custom headers

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this

```
ConfigurationSection httpProtocolSection = 
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol");
ConfigurationElementCollection customHeadersCollection = httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders");
```

For the other values, you have to search for where that value is stored.  For example

```
<compilation debug="true" ...>
```

is stored here

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

Many of the section types, additionally, are stored in System.Web.Configuration

```
System.Web.Configuration.PagesSection
System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlersSection
```

And you can retrieve those with GetSection() as well.

Comment: var customHeaders = (AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customHeaders") and 
var customHeaders = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customHeaders") as NameValueCollection 
both are returning null value.

Comment: I edited it, I realized you needed the XPath of the section for that.

Comment: I am writing this code in global.asax.cs. I want to read web.config files and validate it

Comment: Ah. I misinterpreted that.  Then you need the ConfigurationManager class.  Final edit applied.

Comment: Still it is returning null values

Comment: Below code is working well.

    ConfigurationSection httpProtocolSection = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol");

            var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
            var section = (System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.web");

            var maxRequestLength = 
    section.HttpRuntime.MaxRequestLength;